# Bounce effect when reaching the limit of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am making an animation with canvas, I have managed to make the image (ship.png) to be controlled with the up, right, down and left keys. But I have problems with the bounce effect when reaching the limit of the screen. Could you help me if you could give me some suggestions on how to do it please.

I have tried to make the bounce effect in this part of the code: **this.displacement = function(e)**

I was specifically thinking of putting an OR conditional here: *(e.keyCode == '38')* but I can't think of a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `update`, you can check the direction your ship is moving in and whether it is touching the sides of the canvas. If it is, you flip the speed by multiplying with -1.

I wrote out all the checks for you (see the snippet). You can optimize it a bit by including some more `if else` statements. For example: if you know the ship is moving left, you don't have to do any other bound checks than the left bound one.

```
// Check bounds
const movingLeft = this.ship.get_direction === this.ship.getX && this.ship.getSpeed() < 0;
const touchingLeftBound = this.ship.x <= 0;

const movingRight = this.ship.get_direction === this.ship.getX && this.ship.getSpeed() > 0;
const touchingRightBound = this.ship.x >= this.canvas.width - this.ship.image.width;

const movingUp = this.ship.get_direction === this.ship.getY && this.ship.getSpeed() < 0;
const touchingTopBound = this.ship.y <= 0;

const movingDown = this.ship.get_direction === this.ship.getY && this.ship.getSpeed() > 0;
const touchingBottomBound = this.ship.y >= this.canvas.height - this.ship.image.height;

if (
  (movingLeft && touchingLeftBound) ||
  (movingDown && touchingBottomBound) ||
  (movingUp && touchingTopBound) ||
  (movingRight && touchingRightBound)
) {
  this.ship.setSpeed(this.ship.getSpeed() * -1);
}
```

```js
const CREATION = 100;
const PRECARGE = 200;
const START   = 300;

class spaceship{

   constructor(x, y,image){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.image=image;
      this.speed = 20;//initial speed, before any key
      this.get_direction=null;
      this.set_direction=null;
   }        
   getX() {
     return this.x;
   }
   getY(){
     return this.y;
   }
   getSpeed(){
      return this.speed;
   }    
   setX(x){
      this.x = x;
   }
   setY(y) {
      this.y = y;
   }  
   setSpeed(speed){
      this.speed=speed;
   }     
   setimage(image) {
      this.image = image;
   }
   getimage() {
      return this.image;
   }    
   draw(ctx) {
     ctx.drawImage(this.getimage(),0,0,100,50,this.getX(),this.getY(),100,50);
   }
 }//end of spaceship class 


function Animation(){    
   
   this.state = CREATION;
   this.images  = new Array();
   this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
   this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
   this.aux_canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); // "canvas" refer to the <canvas> tag.
   this.aux_context = this.aux_canvas.getContext("2d")
      
   this.canvas.width=document.body.clientWidth;  //current window size
   this.canvas.height=document.body.clientHeight;
   this.aux_canvas.width=document.body.clientWidth;
   this.aux_canvas.height=document.body.clientHeight;

   this.ship = null;
      
   var object=this;
   
   this.loadImages = function(){

      this.images["ship"] = new Image();
      this.images["ship"].name="ship";
      this.images["ship"].src= "https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQbAW.png";
   }

   this.update = function(){
      this.aux_context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height); //clean the canvas of ships
      this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);    // in both canvases the background is not erased
      this.ship.draw(this.aux_context);
      
      // Check bounds
      const movingLeft = this.ship.get_direction === this.ship.getX && this.ship.getSpeed() < 0;
      const touchingLeftBound = this.ship.x <= 0;

      const movingRight = this.ship.get_direction === this.ship.getX && this.ship.getSpeed() > 0;
      const touchingRightBound = this.ship.x >= this.canvas.width - this.ship.image.width;

      const movingUp = this.ship.get_direction === this.ship.getY && this.ship.getSpeed() < 0;
      const touchingTopBound = this.ship.y <= 0;

      const movingDown = this.ship.get_direction === this.ship.getY && this.ship.getSpeed() > 0;
      const touchingBottomBound = this.ship.y >= this.canvas.height - this.ship.image.height;
      
      if (
        (movingLeft && touchingLeftBound) ||
        (movingDown && touchingBottomBound) ||
        (movingUp && touchingTopBound) ||
        (movingRight && touchingRightBound)
      ) {
        this.ship.setSpeed(this.ship.getSpeed() * -1);
      }
  
      this.context.drawImage(this.aux_canvas,0,0,this.aux_canvas.width,this.aux_canvas.height,0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
      this.ship.set_direction(this.ship.get_direction()+(this.ship.getSpeed()));

   }

   this.displacement = function(e) {

      e = e || window.event;

      if (e.keyCode == '38'|| e.keyCode == '40') {
         //up
         object.ship.set_direction=object.ship.setY;
         object.ship.get_direction=object.ship.getY;    
         if (e.keyCode == '38') //up
            object.ship.setSpeed(-20);
         else//down
            object.ship.setSpeed(20);    
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '37' || e.keyCode == '39') {
         object.ship.set_direction=object.ship.setX;
         object.ship.get_direction=object.ship.getX;        
         if (e.keyCode == '37') //left
            object.ship.setSpeed(-20);
         else//right
            object.ship.setSpeed(20);         
      }

 }

   this.executeMachineStates = function(){
      var imagesUploaded=true;
      if (object.state == CREATION) {
         object.loadImages();
         object.state = PRECARGE;
         setTimeout(object.executeMachineStates, 100);

      } else {
         if(object.state==PRECARGE){

            console.log("state: PRECARGE");
            for(var i=0;i<object.images.length;i++)
               if(object.images[i].complete!=true)
                  imagesUploaded=false;                  
            if(imagesUploaded==true){
               //200 and 100 is the ship's initial position
               object.ship = new spaceship(200, 100,object.images["ship"]);
               object.ship.get_direction=object.ship.getX;  //initial movement
               object.ship.set_direction=object.ship.setX;  //on x-axis
               object.state = START;
               document.onkeydown = object.displacement;
            }
            setTimeout(object.executeMachineStates, 100);
         }else{
            if(object.state==START){
               object.update();
               setTimeout(object.executeMachineStates, 100);
            }
         }
      }
   }

}//end of class/function Animation

animation= new Animation();
animation.executeMachineStates();
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it's clearer now. I will do the recommendation you gave me to optimize it.